# Calculating CRC16-ccitt

Tags: c, calculator, crc

i'm observing one problem i got to solve.

I have to calculate CRC of Hexadecimal entry (from array) and compare it with expected. I don't have polynom.

The array extracted from checksum looks like (example) :

```
unsigned short crcSrc[0x7FFE] = {0xB6FE, 0x8062, 0x2714, 0xB8FE, 0x8066, 0xA940, 0xA743, 0xBCF7, 0x0B87, 0x7E18, 0x070B...... };
```

entries are extracted from file which looks like (just beggining):

```
S0 5A00 0043 3A5C 4441 5445 4E5C 5072 6F6A 656B 7465 5C48 5648 5F48 3130 305F 3830 305C 4170 706C 6963 6174 696F 6E5C 506F 7273 6368 655C 4A31 5C53 6F66 7477 6172 655C 4275 696C 645C 4856 485F 506F 7273 6368 655F 4A31 2E70 726D B9S2 0600 0000 D7F2 30S2 24FE 8000 B6FE 8062 2714 B8FE 8066 A940 A743 BCF7 0B87 7E18 070B 8675 05B9 FE80 6927 10A6 B3S2 24FE 8020 F727 0CA8F71CF7E70B867D2074051B030011FF95A11B03001000BDFA001ED2207A
```

And what i need to do ? i got a right CRC result which is 0xd7f2 and i have to write a calculator to get it. I already found some solutions on internet ,but i still don't have Polynom which is needed to solve this. How can i get it ? Is it hidden somewhere in that file ?

Thank you very much

EDIT : I'm posting my code here how i'm calculating CRC

```
unsigned short crc16(char *data_p, unsigned short length)
 {
  unsigned char i;
  unsigned int data;
  unsigned int crc = 0xffff;

  if (length == 0)
        return (~crc);

  do
  {
        for (i=0, data=(unsigned int)0xff & *data_p++;
             i < 8;
             i++, data >>= 1)
        {
              if ((crc & 0x0001) ^ (data & 0x0001))
                    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ POLY;
              else  crc >>= 1;
        }
  } while (--length);

  crc = ~crc;
  data = crc;
  crc = (crc << 8) | (data >> 8 & 0xff);
  return (crc);
}
```

EDIT 2 : Adding all source [Files to download](http://leteckaposta.cz/606729584)

Comment: CRC-16-CCITT polynomial is - depending how you need it represented in your code - the following: `0x1021` (Normal), `0x8408` (Reversed), `0x811` (Reciprocal), `0x8810` (Reversed reciprocal). List of polynomial values can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks

Comment: http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html has good references and source code for CRC computations. What is required to find yours: a known ASCII or Hexa text and its expected CRC.

Comment: tried every one, but result is still different...should i post here code how i'm calculating it ? Maybe error in it..

Comment: Note: Sample `POLY` not defined.

Comment: Perhaps how code calls `crc16()` is problem.  It is unclear why `unsigned short length` is a short and not a `size_t`.  (how big is the file?).  Posting a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Added files...code and source file is too long so i uploaded it to external server